# In R, how to stack/rbind every N columns using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder if anyone can help me with dividing a longer row to several shorter rows and thereafter unstack them?

1. In this example I have 12-column-long row that I wish to have divided into more rows à 4 columns (see stack_df).
2. The overall plan is to then rowwise unite() all the columns and mutate() to one column (9 rows x 1 column, see merge_df).
3. After that I wish to unstack them back to a dataframe of size: 3 rows, 3 columns (see simple_df.)

Part1 (1/2):

```
> df <- matrix(c("A", "B", "C"),nrow=3,ncol=12,byrow=F)
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"   "A"   "A"  
[2,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"   "B"   "B"  
[3,] "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"   "C"   "C"
```

Part1 (2/2):

```
> stack_df <- matrix(c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3), rep("C",3)), nrow = 9, ncol = 4) 
> stack_df
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [2,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [3,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
 [4,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
 [5,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
 [6,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B" 
 [7,] "C"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
 [8,] "C"  "C"  "C"  "C" 
 [9,] "C"  "C"  "C"  "C"
```

Part2: unite(), mutate(), case_when()

```
    > merge_df <- stack_df %>% 
+   as.data.frame(.) %>% 
+   unite(stack_df, 1:4, na.rm = T) %>% 
+   print()
  stack_df
1  A_A_A_A
2  A_A_A_A
3  A_A_A_A
4  B_B_B_B
5  B_B_B_B
6  B_B_B_B
7  C_C_C_C
8  C_C_C_C
9  C_C_C_C
```

here there is a mutate(), case_when() process.

```
> mutate_df <- cbind(sample(letters,9)) %>% 
+   print()
      [,1]
 [1,] "w" 
 [2,] "q" 
 [3,] "t" 
 [4,] "p" 
 [5,] "r" 
 [6,] "k" 
 [7,] "i" 
 [8,] "o" 
 [9,] "d"
```

Part3: Unstack the rows (to 3 rows, 3 columns). (Desired output)

```
> simple_df <- matrix(mutate_df, nrow = 3, ncol=3, byrow = T)
> simple_df
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "w"  "q"  "t" 
[2,] "p"  "r"  "k" 
[3,] "i"  "o"  "d"
```

Comment: do you know about `tidyr::separate_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

The question names the input `df` as if it were a data frame but it is a matrix and dplyr is typically used with data frames rather than matrices.  dplyr is probably not the correct tool to use here and instead use this base R one-liner where we use the input m in the Note at the end using a more accurate name and also changing the contents to make the result unambiguous.

```
matrix(t(m), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
 [1,] "A1" "A2"  "A3"  "A4" 
 [2,] "A5" "A6"  "A7"  "A8" 
 [3,] "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12"
 [4,] "B1" "B2"  "B3"  "B4" 
 [5,] "B5" "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
 [6,] "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12"
 [7,] "C1" "C2"  "C3"  "C4" 
 [8,] "C5" "C6"  "C7"  "C8" 
 [9,] "C9" "C10" "C11" "C12"
```

or if you intended that the A's fill out the first 3 rows column by column and similarly for the B's and C's

```
matrix(aperm(array(t(m), c(3, 4, 3)), c(1, 3, 2)), ncol = 4)
```

giving:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
 [1,] "A1" "A4" "A7" "A10"
 [2,] "A2" "A5" "A8" "A11"
 [3,] "A3" "A6" "A9" "A12"
 [4,] "B1" "B4" "B7" "B10"
 [5,] "B2" "B5" "B8" "B11"
 [6,] "B3" "B6" "B9" "B12"
 [7,] "C1" "C4" "C7" "C10"
 [8,] "C2" "C5" "C8" "C11"
 [9,] "C3" "C6" "C9" "C12"
```

The above two one-liners could be written using pipelines like this:

```
library(magrittr)

m %>% t %>% matrix(m, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

m %>% t %>% array(c(3, 4, 3)) %>% aperm(c(1, 3, 2)) %>% matrix(ncol = 4)
```

### Note

```
m0 <- matrix(c("A", "B", "C"), 3, 12)
m <- replace(m0, TRUE, paste0(m0, col(m)))
m
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5" "A6" "A7" "A8" "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12"
[2,] "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "B5" "B6" "B7" "B8" "B9" "B10" "B11" "B12"
[3,] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" "C5" "C6" "C7" "C8" "C9" "C10" "C11" "C12"
```